# How to concatenate datasets for tflite model maker?

Tags: tflite

Assume I have datasets loaded from different directories

```
from tflite_model_maker import object_detector

DIR_IMAGES_TRAIN1="/data_dir1"
DIR_IMAGES_TRAIN2="/data_dir2"
DIR_ANNOT_TRAIN1="/annot_dir1"
DIR_ANNOT_TRAIN2="/annot_dir2"
LABEL_MAP = ["custom_object"]

train_data = object_detector.DataLoader.from_pascal_voc(DIR_IMAGES_TRAIN1, DIR_ANNOT_TRAIN1, LABEL_MAP)
train_data2 = object_detector.DataLoader.from_pascal_voc(DIR_IMAGES_TRAIN2, DIR_ANNOT_TRAIN2, LABEL_MAP)
```

How to concatenate them into one?

The [`DataLoader`](https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/api_docs/python/tflite_model_maker/object_detector/DataLoader) doesn't seem to come with a function like '`concatenate`'.